# Window onload function if else statements

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I would like to run different functions depending if a field is checked or not during page load.

So I use `window.onload`. The first *if condition* works great but I would like to add more *if conditions* as defined below. But it doesn't seem to be the proper way.

I thought I could work with *if* and *if else*. Does someone know how to make multiple *if conditions* work for `window.onload` function?

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
if (document.getElementById("field1").checked) {
document.getElementById("field2").style.color = "red";
}
else if (document.getElementById("field3").checked) {
document.getElementById("field4").style.color = "red";
}
<script>
```

Added: I would like to add that all functions must be executed if all the  if statements are fitting (so if else functions are maybe incorrect in this context). If only field1 is fitting the conditions, only the matching field2 should turn colour of text into red.

It’s not about the colour (that’s just an example for a JS function) - in real I want 3 things: enter value X, turn red and get disabled for future inputs (I already coded that - so not necessary).

**UPDATE: Thanks to your comments. I used the code of Emiel Zuurbier: It's working for field 1 until 4 but not for field 10 until 14, did I wrote it wrong?**

```
 <script>
 const fieldMap = [
 ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4'],
 ['field10', 'field11', 'field12', 'field14']
 ];

 window.onload = function() {
  for (const [fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, fieldD] of fieldMap) {
    if (document.getElementById(fieldA).checked) {
        document.getElementById(fieldB).value = "X";
        document.getElementById(fieldB).style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById(fieldB).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById(fieldC).value = "X";
        document.getElementById(fieldC).style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById(fieldC).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById(fieldD).value = "X";
        document.getElementById(fieldD).style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById(fieldD).disabled = true;
     }
   }
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: On which evidence is your conclusion _'it doesn't seem to be the proper way'_ based?

Comment: *I would like to run different JS functions depending if a field is checked or not during page load* - unless you have dynamic page generation on the server-side, there's not much to check in an `onload` event, the controls will be in the state what you've written in the HTML code, so you could also make them red and not-red the same way. In fact even if you have dynamic page generation, this initial "coloring" could be done by the generator too.

Comment: Thank you all for you great ideas, I clarified everything more in my main text. And comments. Really appreciate all of your ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You can eleminate repeating tasks by taking the dynamic parts of your code, in this case your ID selectors, and put them in an array (or object) which you can loop over.

```
const fieldMap = [
  ['field1', 'field2'],
  ['field3', 'field4']
];

window.onload = function() {
  for (const [fieldA, fieldB] of fieldMap) {
    if (document.getElementById(fieldA).checked) {
      document.getElementById(fieldB).style.color = 'red';
    }
  }
}
```

The principle of writing your code like this is called [**DRY** (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://codinglead.co/javascript/what-is-DRY-code)

Comment: Thank you very much, thats new to me and sounds good. So is it right that it’s possible that every girls get checked individual and if condition is fulfilled all fitting  functions are working? 
Like field1 and also field3 are  checked then field 2 and 4 will turn Text red. But if only field 1 is checked only field 3 is turning text into red colour?

Comment: Yes, that is the case. For every set of fields it checks if `fieldA` is checked, and if so, sets the red text on `fieldB`. If any of the fields isn't checked then the text won't be set and vice versa.

Comment: Your idea is awesome! Please check my update in the main post. I can't make it fully work. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: You're welcome, but please refrain from modifiying the question with provided answers. Any new issues should be posted as a new question. Though it's hard to say why it doesn't work without the HTML related to the question. Please post a new question with the HTML, the updated JavaScript and any error messages your console provides.

Answer (score 1):

`winow.onload` executes your `function()` when the page is fully loaded, but it happens just once. If the code you provided is correct then I think you might be missing `}` at the end. However, there's still one thing that bothers me. If you check if a specified checkbox is checked it checks the `checked` property only when the page is fully loaded, not when the user clicks on the `#field` checkbox. If you want the check whether the user checked the checkbox then you can use eventlistener `'check'`.

Comment: Thank you. For events happening based on user clicks after page load I already have a function